# echo a text not a string with HTML formatting on custom fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How to echo a text not string with HTML formatting on custom fields?.
here is my code:

```
<?php
    if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='fr'){
    echo custom_field_excerpt('procedures_paragraph_fr',50);
    }else{
    echo custom_field_excerpt('procedures_paragraph_en',50);
    }
?>
```

Here is my post on Wordpress Post using Advance Custom Fields:

```
**Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada.** 

Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.

Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
```

the output is:

```
Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
```

and when I inspect elements will have `&nbsp;`:

```
<p>Donec&nbsp; sollicitudin&nbsp; molestie&nbsp; malesuada.&nbsp; Nulla&nbsp; quis&nbsp; lorem&nbsp; ut&nbsp; libero&nbsp; malesuada&nbsp; feugiat. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
</p>
```

I want the output to be the same as what is being inputted.

Comment: I cannot tell the difference between the two. Remove the parts that are the same and format the blocks into quotation or code so that we know what to ignore.

Comment: `custom_field_excerpt()` does not appear to be a Wordpress or ACF built-in function. My guess is this is something in your theme's `functions.php` file, and it includes a `strip_tags()` call on the text.

Comment: Why not use acf (advanced custom fields) own functionality for getting values?

Comment: yes that is advance custom fields plugin..I want the character displays only 100 characters..and should be the same output what ive input on wordpress post..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Advanced Custom Fields, why not simply use

```
<?php the_field('NAME_OF_YOUR_FIELD'); ?>
```

?

Comment: the character i want to display is 100 character..what will be the code?. :)

Comment: Do you want to limit the length of what you are displaying, or do you want to limit the length of what the user can write in the admin page?